Combining singleton letters?
I have the following character vector:
vec1 <- c("D R JOHNSON", "NICE W E A T H E R")

This vector has consecutive series of single letters like "D R" which I do NOT want to have spaces between them. For example, I want this vector:
 vec2 <- c("DR JOHNSON", "NICE WEATHER")

Is there any way that, when there is a consecutive series of single letters like "W E A T H E R" I can remove the spaces between these to get "WEATHER"?

This is not entirely correct. Notice that some words cannot be combined since they are single lettters. eg I A M G O OD.  etc. There is no overall code that will combine your words correctly.

You can use look aheads (?=) and look behinds (?<=) with boundaries (\\b):
gsub("(?<=\\b[a-zA-Z]\\b)\\s(?=\\b[a-zA-Z]\\b)", "", vec1, perl=TRUE)


"DR JOHNSON"   "NICE WEATHER"


for shorter, could be "(?<=\\b\\S\\b)\\s(?=\\b\\S\\b)"?

Yes, but I focussed on "consecutive series of single letters"

Split on space, make group id based on consecutive number of characters, then paste with collapse if the number of characters is 1:
f <- function(x){
  s <- unlist(strsplit(x, split = " "))
  paste(sapply(split(s, data.table::rleid(nchar(s))), 
               function(i) { 
                 if(nchar(i)[1] == 1) paste(i, collapse = "") else i 
                 }), 
        collapse = " ")
  }

sapply(vec1, f, USE.NAMES = FALSE)
# [1] "DR JOHNSON"   "NICE WEATHER"

